# How to solve differential equation using Python builtin function odeint?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I want to solve this differential equations with the given initial conditions:

```
(3x-1)y''-(3x+2)y'+(6x-8)y=0, y(0)=2, y'(0)=3
```

the ans should be 
`y=2*exp(2*x)-x*exp(-x)`

here is my code:

```
def g(y,x):
    y0 = y[0]
    y1 = y[1]
    y2 = (6*x-8)*y0/(3*x-1)+(3*x+2)*y1/(3*x-1)
    return [y1,y2]

init = [2.0, 3.0]
x=np.linspace(-2,2,100)
sol=spi.odeint(g,init,x)
plt.plot(x,sol[:,0])
plt.show()
```

but what I get is different from the answer.
what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several things wrong here. Firstly, your equation is apparently

(3x-1)y''-(3x+2)y'-(6x-8)y=0; y(0)=2, y'(0)=3

(note the sign of the term in y). For this equation, your analytical solution and definition of `y2` are correct.

Secondly, as the @Warren Weckesser says, you must pass 2 parameters as `y` to `g`: `y[0]` (y), `y[1]` (y') and return their derivatives, y' and y''.

Thirdly, your initial conditions are given for x=0, but your x-grid to integrate on starts at -2. From the docs for `odeint`, this parameter, `t` in their call signature description:

`odeint(func, y0, t, args=(),...)`:

> t : array
>       A sequence of time points for which to solve for y.  The initial
>       value point should be the first element of this sequence.

So you must integrate starting at 0 or provide initial conditions starting at -2.

Finally, your range of integration covers a singularity at x=1/3. `odeint` may have a bad time here (but apparently doesn't).

Here's one approach that seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(y, x):
    y0 = y[0]
    y1 = y[1]
    y2 = ((3*x+2)*y1 + (6*x-8)*y0)/(3*x-1)
    return y1, y2

# Initial conditions on y, y' at x=0
init = 2.0, 3.0
# First integrate from 0 to 2
x = np.linspace(0,2,100)
sol=odeint(g, init, x)
# Then integrate from 0 to -2
plt.plot(x, sol[:,0], color='b')
x = np.linspace(0,-2,100)
sol=odeint(g, init, x)
plt.plot(x, sol[:,0], color='b')

# The analytical answer in red dots
exact_x = np.linspace(-2,2,10)
exact_y = 2*np.exp(2*exact_x)-exact_x*np.exp(-exact_x)
plt.plot(exact_x,exact_y, 'o', color='r', label='exact')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For a second order differential equation, `init` should have length 2, not 3 (and `g` should return a length 2 array).

Comment: You're right: I got confused. I've edited to correct it.